# In Android Studio, how do I change the Flutter naming conventions?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, lint

Apparently Google and/or JetBrains think everyone ought to use CamelCase, but (a) I prefer snake_case (use of underscores), (b) nearly every line of my sources now has a lint complaint, making it hard to separate the wheat from the chaff, and (c) I don't have time to rewrite all my code just to pander to other people's aesthetic sense.
How do I convince AS to be a Philistine like me?

Android Studio has a Kotlin naming convention in inspection settings

but It seems Android Studio does not have a flutter naming convetion in inspetion settings

Comment: The reason Dart have a [Style guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) is to ensure a consistent style across the entire Dart ecosystem, and to makes it easier for all of us to read and understand other's code. What you are asking is not to make it easier for you, but to make it harder for others.

Comment: you can switch on/off some linter warnings, try searchimg for `camel` in https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/, more on linter here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: @pskink I really appreciate it. copy and paste it for answer I will adopt. I created the analysis_options.yaml file as docs descirbe then it worked

Comment: it was just a hint: post a self answer with a specific info what you placed inside `analysis_options.yaml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I referenced some documents @pskink saying, https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-linter-rules

since I wanted to use underscore when creating a variable, what I did is

Firstly, making a analysis_options.yaml file in top level directories like pubspec.yaml

Secondly, then implement like this in analysis_options.yaml

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

linter: 
  rules:
non_constant_identifier_names: false
```

and Lastly in pubspec.yaml file,

```
dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
```

then no more showing "Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase."

Answer (score 0):

find "analysis_options.yaml", and add this under rules:

```
  rules:
    file_names:false
```